# Fiddlercap not capturing in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, fiddler

I'm debugging a JS problem on a client's app.  So I gave him Fiddlercap to record him reproducing the problem.

Except - fiddler cap isn't capturing anything (it captures the fiddler cap welcome URL).  He's a developer, so am sure he understood the instructions.

Any idea what could cause this, all I know is the app is running remotely and is not HTTPS.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, without more details, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help. What browser is he using? If it's Firefox, he needs to configure it to use the System Proxy setting.

Comment: @EricLaw thanks - IE8.  Unfortunately it's one of those situations where you're already debugging something, the last thing you want to do is debug the debugger with someone who just wants the problem gone...  Anyway in this case there was a happy ending via a different route.